# How can I use an eclipse environment variable as GDB path?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt, environment

I need to use a specific file as "gdb" executable in Eclipse. In the "Debug Configurations" window, "Debugger" tab for a C/C++ Application, one can specify the executable through path. I would expect it is also possible to refer to the executable using a Eclipse environment variable but I cannot find the proper way to write this.

I have declared DEBUG_EXEC as Eclipse environment variable through: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked resources. And made this variable point to a specific file on my harddrive.

How could I refer to this variable?

Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK you can only refer to these variables: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but it was highly ranked on Google, so here goes.

You can achieve what you want by creating your variable in Preferences -> Run/Debug -> String Substitution.

If you create a variable called `gdb_path`, you can then refer to it in the Debug Configuration as `${gdb_path}`. It will also appear in the list of variables when clicking the Variables button next to the GDB Command text field.